# Need to get the tool tip text from the active span element located inside another span in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In this application, there is an option to activate or deactivate a channel.

When this channel is activated, span containing tool tip to deactivate is activated like shown below.
[image: chanel activated]

Similarly, When this channel is de-activated, span containing tool tip to activate is activated like shown below.

[image: channel de-activated]

If I can figure out the xpath to active span I would be able to verify this element. BUt having hard time to find the xpath to **active** span.

```
</span>
                                      <span id="stat965"> 
                                            <span class="btn btn-small deactivateBtn btn-warning" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="status('ZVJxWHlYYUhMaWxZM2xqT1A2YTdydz09' ,'false','TWITTER',965);" title="" data-original-title="Deactivate">
                                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="btn btn-small activateBtn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" style="display: none;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="status('ZVJxWHlYYUhMaWxZM2xqT1A2YTdydz09' ,'true','TWITTER',965);" title="" border="0" data-original-title="Activate"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                            </span>

                                    </span>
```

[image: code for validation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isDisplayed` method on following web elements which tell whether that element is visible on the web page or not.

try for `Deactivate` span tag with following XPATH:

```
//span[@style="display: inline-block;"  and @data-original-title="Deactivate"]
```

returns WebElement `only if Deactivate span tag is active` otherwise null, so you can check for Activate span tag.

for `Activate` span tag with following XPATH:

```
//span[@style="display: inline-block;"  and @data-original-title="Activate"]
```

Comment: If i use this i always get deactivate which is the first present in the code. If i can find which span is active, i can get the tool tip using above xpath. But how to find the active span.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy   updated the answer. please try it out.

Comment: there is no error. Selenium is identifying the element as active always. issue with identifying the element. i have given code screen shot above

Comment: try with isDisplayed instead of isEnabled. As only one element is visible from one of the two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128347/discussion-between-naveen-and-nagarjuna-reddy).

Comment: you can join the link mentioned in above comment to assist you. isDisplayed worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below CSS for to identify Activate :

```
span.activateBtn
```

Please try the below CSS for to identify De-Activate :

```
span.deactivateBtn
```

Comment: identifying the active span is the issue here. If i can identify then i can get the tool tip, match it and then i can verify it.

Answer (score 0):

According to you, only one element (span) should be active. Right? If yes, you can use enabled method. Enabled method will return true if element is enabled. As per your need, you can process the return value. Example:

```
  if(driver.findelement(By.xpath("//span[@data-original-title="Deactivate"]).enabled)
{
// do your actions
}
```

And check the same for activate element and continue your steps as per your need.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[1]/td[5]/div/span[3]//span[@data-original-title=\"Deactivate\"]")).isEnabled() is not working. Selenium is taking always the deactivate as it's written first in the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find the deactive span, use the below cssSelector:

```
span[class*="deactivateBtn"]
```

for choosing deactivate span, use the below cssSelector:

```
span[class*="activateBtn"]
```

hope this helps and let me know what is the result.